# Voice morphing iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, objective-c, voice

I want to do voice morphing for the recorded voice (i.e) I want to change the voice that cat speaks,Can you please suggest me a way or an algorithm to do so.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Look into OpenAL, an audio framework already present in ios. It has the ability to record and play back - morphing the sound via pitch and virtual 3d location. Mainly, you'd probably want the pitch morph function to make a cat.